# Можно ли так сказать?

Tags: сочетаемость

"Очень" (как и "достаточно", "слишком" и т.п.) передает степень качества, выражаемого прилагательным, т.е. строго по норме сочетается только с качественными прилагательными.

Значит, нельзя сказать *очень много*?

Answer (score 4):

Можно, ибо **много** может быть и **не очень**( не очень много). Слово "много" не является превосходной степенью, "очень" может её создать. Есть много, есть довольно много, есть очень много, особенно много и, наконец, - бесконечно много. А вот, например, к наречию  **немерено**(денег у него немерено), которое можно считать синонимом сочетанию **очень** **много**, "очень" не прирастишь, та как оно выражает высшую степень данного определения.

Answer (score 4):

Степень может быть не только у качества, но и у признака, так же, как степени сравнения имеют не только качественные прилагательные, но и наречия на -О, от них образованные: очень ярко, очень темно, очень светло. Вот у признака наречия МНОГО (большое количество)тоже есть степень меньшая и большая.Очень и не очень много, очень мало и не очень мало.